# Django view retrieve the object from the database

Tags: django, django-views

I had a Product object in models,

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique = True)
    description = models.TextField()
    image_url = models.URLField(verify_exists=True, max_length=200, blank = True, null = True)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def sell(self, save=True):
        self.quantity -= 1
        if save:
            self.save()
```

and a template called:product_view.html   `Product {{product.title}}`
and a template called:product_list.html  `{% for p in products %}{{p.id}},{% endfor %}`

I want to make the view retrieve the Product object from the database, use it to render the template and finally return an HttpResponse object that contains the resulting string. If the Product with the given product_id can not be found raise a 404 exception (or return HttpResponseNotFound)

```
def productview(request, product_id):
  """
  I dont know how to write here
  """
  #render template "product_view.html" with param product
  return HttpResponse("product %s" % product_id)
```

Meanwhile,if i want to render a page with a list of all available products. A product is available if it has a quantity that's bigger than 0. The template product_list.html is expecting a single parameter products in the context which refers to an iterable of Product objects.

So how to make the view retrieve the the available products and how to use them to render the template and return an HttpResponse object that contains the resulting string?

```
def available_products(request):
    """
    I dont know how to write here
    """
    #render template "product_list.html" with param products
    return HttpResponse("View not implemented!")
```

Thx very much

Comment: do you want to render a template or return a string?

Comment: Funny, I'm solving exactly the same homework exercise as you were : )
Only that instead of "I dont know how to write here" there should be:
"""
Write your view implementations for exercise 4 here.
Remove the current return line below.
"""

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)?

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_view.html'


class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'product_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Here you can filter the product list
        """
        query_set = super(ProductListView, self).get_queryset()
        return query_set.filter(quantity__gt=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import Product 

def productview(request):
    """
    Retrive all products
    """
    products = Product.objects.all() 
    return render_to_response('product_list.html',{'products': products})

def available_products(request):
    """
    Retrive available products
    """
    products = Product.objects.filter(quantity__gt=0) 
    return render_to_response('product_list.html',{'products': products})
```

These two also can be combined in one view, depending on defined url pattern. 
For example:

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^product/(?P<which>\w+)/$', 'app_label.views.product_view'),
)

#views.py
def product_view(request, which):
    """
    Retrive available products
    """
    if which == 'all':
        products = Product.objects.all() 
    else:
        products = Product.objects.filter(quantity__gt=0) 
    return render_to_response('product_list.html',{'products': products})
```